# "error setting certificate" issue in R

Tags: r, twitter

I can't figure out how to fix this error I keep getting in R:

> error setting certificate verify locations:\n  CAfile: \n  CApath: none\n
>       Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : 
>         Error: error setting certificate verify locations:
>         CAfile: 
>         CApath: none

I'm trying to use the `twitteR` package to gather tweets from the below function. It was working fine yesterday, but I can't find a way to fix the certificate issue.

```
TweetFrame <- function(searchTerm, maxTweets)  
{
  twtList<-searchTwitter(searchTerm,n=maxTweets)
  #twtList is involved in “variable” scoping so it only exists within the function  
  # searchTerm needs to be a string so use "#hashtag"

  twtTempFrame<- do.call("rbind", lapply(twtList,as.data.frame))
  # as.data.frame() coerces each list element into a row
  # lapply() applies this to all of the elements in twtList
  # rbind() takes all the rows and puts them together
  # do.call() gives rbind() all the rows as individual elements

  return(twtTempFrame[order(as.integer(twtTempFrame$created)), ])

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this package. But maybe this http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html can help you. It solved my certificate problem I had with another R package.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried using download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem") with credential$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")) I saw recommended on another thread here but it didn't fix the issue. I'm sure it's something related to that, but I'm not sure what exactly is "broken" about it when it was working perfectly fine before.